# Codeigniter DB Class is it possible to store a JSON object in a table, using this class? if so how?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to store an object in a column on one of my tables, its sort of a settings logic, but I am in the process of conforming my older styling of `mysql_query()` style querys into the active record methods. Of which I am now getting a

> "Duplicate Entry" for PRIMARY

as an error from the DB Class, and the only thing I can associate it with is, the fact that I am attempting to pass this object which is being escaped, and I think its breaking the insert/update query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use `json_decode()` (http://www.php.net/json_decode) and make sure it will be conform to the table-rows. Use typecasting if needed to force certain values to be correct.

`json_encode()` will store your JSON string to a native PHP Array, thus making it easy to work with it from there to format it into your DB Table's format.

If you add some code to your questions, I can probably give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Doh, I just figured it out, had nothing to do with what I was doing with the JSON object turns out. It was that I was calling to the same function twice as I have multiple functions in my class for various inserts/updates to different tables. In that by calling one function in succession of the same function prior I was essentially trying to insert the same data into the same table twice